how to color UNICHAR in dax
I have a code as below and i would like to color it in dax code rather then using format visuals in powerbi. is there a way to do that ? many thanks in advance.
diffs = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(), 
    [measure] < 0,
    UNICHAR(9660), BLANK())


There are special coloured unicode chars you can use but there are a limited number. e.g. a red down triangle
UNICHAR(128315)

https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+1F53B
